# In Pandas, how to find row using exactly date

Tags: python, pandas

I have an dataframe, with date as index, I have an date object, I am trying to locate the row with that exact date, this is what I have:

```
candle.loc[candle.index == targetdate]
```

This is my date object:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 8, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
```

This is my dataframe:

```
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                            
2020-12-31  371.779999  374.660004  371.230011  373.880005  372.659454  78520700
```

When I try to run the code it return me an empty frame but you can see the date is in the dataframe, how do I get it?

Comment: Is `datetime.datetime(...)` your `targetdate`?

Comment: yes, I just print it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get date part from datetime and convert to string:

```
>>> candle.loc[candle.index == str(targetdate.date())]

                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume
Date
2020-12-31  371.779999  374.660004  371.230011  373.880005  372.659454  78520700
```